# Simplifying Boolean algebra question

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm not quite sure how to go about simplifying this boolean expression, any help would be great.

X'Y'+X'Z'+Y'Z

Comment: What do you mean by X' ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Could you please provide more information about the problem?  Specifically, your notation.  Also, it would be helpful to express any ideas you have about solving the problem.

Comment: X' = NOT X. I know most of the laws and I can figure out most basic questions, however on this question all I can think of is to do the distribution law to get X'(Y'+Z')+YZ' but then i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the three terms to two terms:

$$\begin{align}
X'Y'+X'Z'+Y'Z &= X'Y'(Z + Z') + X'Z' + Y'Z \\
& = Z(X'Y' + Y') + Z'(X'Y'+X') \\
& = X'Z' + Y'Z 
\end{align}$$